# How to check if form elements are not empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I check if all the elements inside a form "textbox, checkbox, textarea, select, file" are not empty?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can see if any are empty like this:

```
$(":input").each(function() {
   if($(this).val() === "")
    alert("Empty Fields!!");
});
```

[You can read on the :input selector here](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/)

for a more specific answer, if you only want those types, change the selector like this:

```
$(":text, :file, :checkbox, select, textarea").each(function() {
   if($(this).val() === "")
    alert("Empty Fields!!");
});
```

Comment: @From.ME.to.YOU - You want to require that all checkboxes be checked?  Make sure you want to do that first, often you don't.  If it's an "Agree to terms" it makes sense...if it's not then why have the checkbox instead of just `true`?  If you do indeed need them checked change the if to this: `if(($(this).is(":checkbox") && !$(this).is(":checked")) || $(this).val() === "")`

Comment: I might also recommend a `jQuery.trim` before a `===` check against `""`, `if($.trim($(this).val()) === '') { // ...`

Comment: This also not works for a series of radios because all radios can not be checked at once.

Comment: how to use it for a specific form, If I am having more forms.

Comment: $("#formId").find(":text, :file, :checkbox, select, textarea").each(function () {
                if (($(this).is(":checkbox") && !$(this).is(":checked")) || $(this).val() !== "")
                   allFieldsEmpty = false;
            });