# Using jQuery .val() to obtain value of input - Data is loaded from database

Tags: jquery

I have a particular issue. The data inside of my HTML `<input>` elements is loaded from a database.

As result, when I try to obtain the value of these input boxes to use in the below function, "obtainAPIData", it returns undefined because the values have not loaded yet.

I need to wait for the input fields to populate with the data from the database - before I use `.val()`

```
var weight = $('#letterhead_weight').val();
var size = $('#letterhead_size').val();
var type = $('#letterhead_type').val();

obtainAPIData('get_letterhead', '#product_info', 'JSON', type, weight, size);
```

Comment: When are they loading? Are you using AJAX or something?

Comment: So wait... what is the problem???

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469999/jquery-how-to-check-if-form-elements-are-not-empty for the answer.

Comment: @MarkBubel. Did you read his question?!

Comment: Does the function obtainAPIData have a callback? I'm presuming you're using ajax so you must be able to use a callback when the ajax request completes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is your data being pulled from the database?

If it's **synchronous** to the page you could just wrap it in a document.ready style call in order to wait for the page to fully load before firing.

```
$(function(){
   var weight = $('#letterhead_weight').val();
   var size = $('#letterhead_size').val();
   var type = $('#letterhead_type').val();

   obtainAPIData('get_letterhead', '#product_info', 'JSON', type, weight, size);
});
```

If it's an **async** call you'll need to put a callback function on your database retrieval routine in order to fire your JS when it's complete.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: function() { 
      var weight = $('#letterhead_weight').val();
      var size = $('#letterhead_size').val();
      var type = $('#letterhead_type').val();

      obtainAPIData('get_letterhead', '#product_info', 'JSON', type, weight, size); 
  },
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the values of the variables in the success() function the AJAX request:

```
// declare them outside of the ajax function, so that you have access
// to them throughout your script
    var var1;
    var var2;

$.ajax({
  url: "test.php",
  success: function(response){
     var1 = response.data1;
     var2 = response.data2;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really understanding how can you load from batabase after body is loaded, but you can use the `delay()` function and it will wait the value you set.

```
//NOT RECOMMENDED
var weight = $('#letterhead_weight').delay('MILISECS').val();
var size = $('#letterhead_size').delay('MILISECS').val();
var type = $('#letterhead_type').delay('MILISECS').val();
obtainAPIData('get_letterhead', '#product_info', 'JSON', type, weight, size);
```

or if it is loaded at the same time as de document, just use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var weight = $('#letterhead_weight').val();
var size = $('#letterhead_size').val();
var type = $('#letterhead_type').val();
 obtainAPIData('get_letterhead', '#product_info', 'JSON', type, weight, size);
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: Lets say you set delay of 5 secs and for some reason it took 10 sec to populate those input fields. How will you handle those situations.. Delay is not an option here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not waiting for the DOM to be ready. Wrap your code inside dom ready event. Try this.

```
$(function(){
   var weight = $('#letterhead_weight').val();
   var size = $('#letterhead_size').val();
   var type = $('#letterhead_type').val();

   obtainAPIData('get_letterhead', '#product_info', 'JSON', type, weight, size);
});
```