# ask for saving before leaving the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469999/jquery-how-to-check-if-form-elements-are-not-empty) I am asking confirmation from user to save data 
before leaving the page,if user enter any data in the textfields.

but I am getting below error when page loads and my form id is "Form1"

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
     window.onload = function (e) {
        var form_has_been_modified = 0;
          $("form[id^='Form1']").on("change keyup", ":input", function () {
          form_has_been_modified = 1;
        })
        };
     window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
           if (!form_has_been_modified) {
             return;
        }
        var message = "Do you want to save the data before leave the page?";
        var e = e || window.event;

         // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
        if (e) {
              e.returnValue = message;
        }
        // For Safari
         return message;
             };


        </script>
```

how to solve this issue?

**Updated: in HTML source code shows  `<form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="EditMember.aspx?Id=3664653" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="aspnetForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">`, How to use this form in above code?**

Answer (score 4):

Method [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) was added to jQuery version 1.7.

It seems that you are using version 1.4.1. Try to update jQuery and the error should disappear.

Comment: I added 1.8.1 version to master page and Master page form id is "Form1" and moved above script to child page where it needed. I am still getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is wrong

$("form[id^='Form1']") Should be $("#Form1")

Also don't forget there might be more then just input tags (select and textarea for example)