# Check to see if form fields are empty using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have a working function that checks if all of the forms fields are not blank. For part of a form, i have a hidden div that will appear if one of the fields has an answer of yes selected in the drop down. when i have the drop down item selected as yes, i would like for the function to check if any one of those fields are left empty, and when the drop down has an answer of no, i don't want the function to check the values of the hidden div items. i can't seem to figure out a way to accomplish this. this is what i have tried so far. the variable label2 contains the value of the drop down menu, Yes/No.

```
function validateOverage()
{
    var drive2 = document.forms["overage"]["drivers2"].value;
    var prodes2 = document.forms["overage"]["proddes2"].value;
    var sizes2 = document.forms["overage"]["size2"].value;
    var cases2 = document.forms["overage"]["cs2"].value;
    var bottle2 = document.forms["overage"]["btls2"].value;
    var initials2 = document.forms["overage"]["chkitls2"].value;
    var label2 = document.forms["overage"]["ontrucks"].value;
    var routenum2 = document.forms["overage"]["routenum"].value;
    var stopnum2 = document.forms["overage"]["stopnum"].value;
    var custnum2 = document.forms["overage"]["custnum"].value;
    if (drive2 == null || drive2 == "" || prodes2 == null || prodes2 == "" || sizes2 == null || sizes2 == "" || cases2 == null || cases2 == ""||
    bottle2 == null || bottle2 == "" || initials2 == null || initials2 == "" || label2 == null || label2 == "")
    {
        alert("Fill in all Fields for the Overage form");
        return false;
    }
    else if (label2 == "Yes" || routenum2 == null || routenum2 == "" || stopnum2 == null || stopnum2 == "" || custnum2 == null || custnum2 == "")
    {
        alert("Fille in all Fields for the Overage form");
        return false;
    }*/
    else if (cases2 == "0" && bottle2 == "0")
    {
        alert("Both cases and bottles values can not be 0");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Data Added to the Overage form");
    }
}
```

html code that i have in my body that has the hidden contents

```
<td style = "visibility: hidden"><input type = "number" id = "routenum"> </input></td>
            <td style = "visibility: hidden"><input type = "number" id = "stopnum"> </input></td>
            <td style = "visibility: hidden"><input type = "number" id = "custnum"> </input></td>
```

Comment: Most of your checks are superfluous, an elements value will never be `null`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if form elements are not empty?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469999/how-to-check-if-form-elements-are-not-empty)

Comment: You mean `(label2 =="Yes" && drive2 == "")`

Comment: delete all your null values for the text inputs, replace `|| label2 == null || label2 == ""` with `&& label2 == "your value for this, probably yes"`

Comment: div? i dont see any div's?

Comment: @KevinKloet i just included the html portion that is being hidden in the form. basically, the label variable will have the value of yes or no. if the value is yes, 3 elements that are hidden will appear. when the user selects yes and the 3 hidden elements appear, i'm trying to have the same functionality if any one of those 3 inputs are empty, to have an alert appear saying that all of the fields are not filled in.

Comment: @  adeneo: no that's right, but with == it will evaluate to null, or to false, or to 0, ...

Comment: @dxcorzo i don't see how that applies in my case. in my case, i have 3 hidden inputs which will only appear if the value for label is yes. the way that i am understanding the answer that was presented in that thread, even if the value for label is set to no, the function will still iterate through and still them me that there are empty fields.