# Check Element has which form Input

Tags: jquery

I have an element which contains some inputs like Radio, Text, Select Box Nothing is fix right. I've tried something like:

```
$(this).attr('type);
```

This  is failing when element is a Select Box. I'm coming to the point I need to check whatever Form Input element has I need to validate (Is checked, Is Selected(SelectBox), Is Not Empty(Textbox)). How can I achieve this?

Note that I'm not willing to use a 3rd party library. I would like to use plain jQuery only.

**Update**

> What I want is I wanted to check:  1). One thing is fix like div
>   contains some input fields Like Radio, Select , Text Input , Checkbox
>   etc. 2). I dont know what it will be. 3). I need to validate those
>   fields using jQuery wheather one is empty or not.

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. All you've explained it what doesn't work. You haven't told us what you're attempting to do, or why.

Comment: *Note that I'm not willing to use a 3rd party library. I would like to use plain jQuery only.* jQuery **is** a third party library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if form elements are not empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469999/how-to-check-if-form-elements-are-not-empty)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand this correctly, you want to check what value your select element is returning when a form is submitted using JQuery.

In that case it should be something like:
    $('select-el').children('option:selected').val();

That should be included inside the relevant function.

Do agree with the comments though. Please add more context.

Comment: Check My Update.

Comment: We are going to need more information
For example:
Does 'I don't know what it will be' mean that that data is dynamic
If you have example code, please post. Will give us a better idea.